# how to get drop down of month and set default value as current month (also in year) in angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs, datetime, drop-down-menu

I have a two dropdown of Month and Year. The dropdown of year has 10 options from 2105-2025. While Open html page how can i set default value of current year and current date?

For example Today is May 2019. So for today I can put the value of `vm.Search.Month = 3;` and `vm.Search.Year=2019;` but doing this i have to change the value of `vm.Search.Month` and `vm.Search.Year` every month and year. How can I set the default value so i dosen't have to change its value??

//this is the dropdown in angular for Date

```
vm.monthList = [
    { Value: 1, Text: 'Jan' },
    { Value: 2, Text: 'Feb' },
    { Value: 3, Text: 'Mar' },
    { Value: 4, Text: 'Apr' },
    { Value: 5, Text: 'May' },
    { Value: 6, Text: 'June' },
    { Value: 7, Text: 'July' },
    { Value: 8, Text: 'Aug' },
    { Value: 9, Text: 'Sep' },
    { Value: 10, Text: 'Oct' },
    { Value: 11, Text: 'Nov' },
    { Value: 12, Text: 'Dec' }
];
```

//Similarly this is the drodown for Year in angular JS

```
vm.yearList = [
    { Value: 2015, Text: '2015' },
    { Value: 2016, Text: '2016' },
    { Value: 2017, Text: '2017' },
    { Value: 2018, Text: '2018' },
    { Value: 2019, Text: '2019' },
    { Value: 2020, Text: '2020' },
    { Value: 2021, Text: '2021' },
    { Value: 2022, Text: '2022' },
    { Value: 2023, Text: '2023' },
    { Value: 2024, Text: '2024' },
    { Value: 2025, Text: '2025' }
];
```

//my HTML fro year and month are

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <md-input-container class="block">
            <div class="col-xs-5 pad-0">
                <label class="md-no-float md-container-ignore ">
                  Year
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 pad-col-7">
                <div class="form-group" id="helpblockforrequired">
                    <md-select class="md-no-asterisk"
                               ng-model="vm.Search.Year" name="Year"
                               ng-change="onContractTypeChange()"
                               id="Year" required>
                        <md-option ng-value="dateYear.Value"
                                   ng-repeat="dateYear in vm.yearList">
                          {{dateYear.Text}}
                        </md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

//html for Month DropDown

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <md-input-container class="block">
        <div class="col-xs-5 pad-0">
            <label class="md-no-float md-container-ignore">Month</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 pad-col-7">
            <md-select class="md-no-asterisk"
                       ng-model="vm.Search.Month" name="Month"
                       ng-change="onContractTypeChange()"
                       id="Month" required>
                <md-option ng-value="dateMonth.Value"
                           ng-repeat="dateMonth in vm.monthList">
                  {{dateMonth.Text}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
vm.Search.Year = new Date().getFullYear();
vm.Search.Month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
```

*Note* : `getMonth()` is a method that returns current month, but January = 0.